# What are the pythonic & MVC friendly ways to write functions in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm creating a simple app with Django 1.8.4 which allows users to share links from other websites and vote up and vote down functions. There were some reusable apps out there to handle this but I preferred to write my own code to "learn" Django. But after few days of trying I think I've got a pretty bad code. It works almost fine, but it doesn't seem really pythonic to me and also I think it's not the right way to do things in Django.

Here's the part of code for handling votes:

models.py

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    UP, DOWN = range(2)
    TYPE_CHOICES = [(UP, "Upvote"), (DOWN, "DownVote")]

    voter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link, related_name='votes')
    vote_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, db_index=True)
    vote_date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now=True)
```

Then I pass this model to a simple form, and here's the template code:
link_detail.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'vote' %}" class="vote_form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" id="id_link" name="link" class="hidden_id" value="{{ link.pk }}"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="id_link" name="voter" class="hidden_id" value="{{ user.pk }}"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="id_link" name="vote_type" class="hidden_id" value="0"/>        
            <button> + </button>
            [up votes: {{ link.up_votes}}]
        </form>

        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'vote' %}" class="vote_form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" id="id_link" name="link" class="hidden_id" value="{{ link.pk }}"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="id_link" name="voter" class="hidden_id" value="{{ user.pk }}"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="id_link" name="vote_type" class="hidden_id" value="1"/>        
            <button> - </button>
            [down votes: {{ link.down_votes }}]
        </form>
```

And the most ugly part to me is the views.py. I think I'd better change many duplicated if expressions with simpler functions:

```
class VoteFormView(FormView):
    form_class = VoteForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        v_user = self.request.user
        v_link = get_object_or_404(Link, pk=form.data["link"])
        v_type = form.data['vote_type']

        up_votes = Vote.objects.filter(voter=v_user, link=v_link, vote_type=0)
        down_votes = Vote.objects.filter(voter=v_user, link=v_link, vote_type=1)

        up_voted = (up_votes.count() > 0)
        down_voted = (down_votes.count() > 0)

        if (v_type == "1") and not down_voted:
            print ("%s has not voted down_voted %s") % (v_user, v_link)
            Vote.objects.create(voter=v_user, link=v_link, vote_type=v_type)
            with transaction.atomic():
                Link.objects.filter(pk=form.data["link"]).update(down_votes=F('down_votes')+1)
            print("down voted")
        elif (v_type == "1") and down_voted:
            down_votes[0].delete()
            Link.objects.filter(pk=form.data["link"]).update(down_votes=F('down_votes')-1)
            print("unvoted")
        elif(v_type == "0") and not up_voted:
            print ("%s has not voted up_voted %s") % (v_user, v_link)
            Vote.objects.create(voter=v_user, link=v_link, vote_type=v_type)
            Link.objects.filter(pk=form.data["link"]).update(up_votes=F('up_votes')+1)
            print("voted")
        elif (v_type == "0") and up_voted:
            up_votes[0].delete()
            Link.objects.filter(pk=form.data["link"]).update(up_votes=F('up_votes')-1)
            print("unvoted")
        return redirect("home")
```

I just looked at some other apps like [django-vote](https://github.com/Beeblio/django-vote) which seems pretty nice to me. But it's not what I want and actually I don't understand how it works completely.

Saying all of these, here's my question: I want to write some separated functions, to check if a user has been voted before, check the vote's type, and finally apply the vote to the models using F() function and increase the user's reputation. But I don't know where to put these codes? in models.py for example or write new managers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some quick observations:

It looks to me as if you are placing code that uses the values from the form in a view. So why not put that logic in the form itself, probably in the save() method, as the VoteForm should be used for saving/creating/updating Votes.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['commit'] = False
    vote = super(VoteForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

You dont need to test for count() > 0, as empty QS will return False. I'd split the logic into two nested if statements, as if vtype isnt 0, its 1.

```
if v_type == '0':
    if up_voted:
        <do stuff>
    else:
        <do downvoted stuff>
else:
    if up_voted:
        <do stuff>
    else:
        <do downvoted stuff>
```

Note you have an unsaved instance of Vote returned from super, so you can use it in place of your create statements above. I would also make a LinkManager class that can upvote/downvote. Your F statement use is presumably for speed, as it doesnt pull the Link into memory. Also no need to use filter, as pk is unique.

```
LinkManager(models.Manager):
    def update_up_votes(self, pk, increment=True):
        self.get(pk=pk).update(up_votes=F('up_votes')+1) if increment else self.get(pk=pk).update(up_votes=F('up_votes')-1)
```

Hopefully some of this is useful to get you refactoring a bit.

EDIT:

You can use the LinkManager method(s) in place of the Link.objects.filter().update()s in your code. It refactors it to the manager. So for upvoting

```
Link.objects.update_up_votes(pk)
```

Or decrementing an upvote

```
Link.objects.update_up_votes(pk, increment=False)
```

Remember you have to add your custom manager to your Link class through objects.

For your template - I didn't really look at it, but just doing {{form.as_p}} on the VoteForm will give you all the fields already formatted. You dont need two forms, as they post to the same view. Just do your logic in the view to decide. You also don't need access to the user there either, as your Vote has it through vote.voter.

Comment: Actually it is very helpful. But I'm a little bit confused about calling the LinkManager Method. Where should I call it from? From the views instead of <do stuff> part for example?

Comment: And any idea about duplicated lines in the template?